# Using Wikipedia API on custom wikis like Bulbapedia

Tags: json, rest, wiki, wikipedia, pokemon-go

Does anyone have experience in using the [Wiki API Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) with making REST calls on custom wikis? By custom wiki I mean something like http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/.

I particularly want to get access to some of the Pokemon content found on [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_base_stats_(Generation_VI-present)), but not sure where to start or if it's even possible to use REST on custom wikis.

### My current solution is to just use a standard wikipedia page with calls like:

- To Get All Pokemon:

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon
- To Get Bulbasaur:

  - https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Bulbasaur

I get some JSON that I can work with, but would love to be able to explore the content of a Bulbapedia page AND have access to all of Ken Sugimori's artwork.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MediaWiki comes with API bundled. Furthermore, since 1.27 it includes a rewritten ApiSandbox that I originally wrote as an extension. So as Bulbapedia is running 1.27.1, it [has the sandbox too](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox).

Comment: Perfect, I'll  look into it :). So all wikis have access to the sandbox from the directory _"/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox"_ ?

Comment: This answer is spot on. Here is a direct link to the API to parse the Bulbasaur page on bulbapedia -- similar to the wikipedia example in the original post: https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)